# How to generate font file with Unicode support for three.js?

Tags: html, fonts, three.js, typeface

I am testing three.js TextGeometry elements with text containing non-Latin glyphs, such as Cyrillic and Chinese glyphs, using the Helvetiker typeface.

The rendered test elements contain question marks in place of non-Latin characters, presumably because Helvetiker only includes some subset of Latin characters.

I'd like to make a replacement for Helvetiker. How are TTF typefaces rendered into JS equivalents, so that I could test taking an open-source typeface and including the glyph sets I am interested in, and render text in three.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert any font to Three.js. See http://blog.andrewray.me/creating-a-3d-font-in-three-js/ . But if the font itself doesn't have the characters, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 5):

As per the manual http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/TextGeometry you can use http://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/ to create new typefaces for your app.